# Google App Engine python search API sample project - Bad API key for Maps

Tags: google-app-engine, google-maps-api-3

I'm following the Google App Engine sample project that demonstrates using the Python Search API - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/training/fts_intro/

within the Readme.MD file, in the product_search_python directory -

> Before you deploy the application, edit `app.yaml` to specify your own
>   app id and version.
>
> In `templates/product.html`, the Google Maps API is accessed.  It does
>   not require an API key, but you are encouraged to use one to monitor
>   your maps usage.
>
> In the  element, look for:
>   src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"
>
> and replace it with something like the following, where
>   `replaceWithYourAPIKey` is your own API key:
>
> ```
>   src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;key=replaceWithYourAPIKey"
> ```
>
> as described
>   [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key).

My code is as follows -

```
<title>Product Information for {{pname}}</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">google.load("jquery", "1"); google.load("jqueryui", "1");</script>
<script
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;key=AIzaSyDpQ9voO3bbkgf6RJHhpvjRQktmx562zzz"
  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/StyledMarker.js"></script>
```

(Last three zzz's on the end are to obscure my API key.

Here's my product.html file - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1308556/Code/product.html

Here's a video of having the code open in my editor, verifying the API key in my GCE developer console, deploying, and receiving the error in my browser - http://youtu.be/Ae-xXZFzm2I

Thanks!

Comment: You obfuscated your key in the code above but then it shows it in the video...

Comment: I'm ok with that if it helps lead to an answer :)

Comment: Does this only occur on localhost or do you get the same error when you deploy your application?

Comment: I fixed it! See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

So, after trying about everything I decided to just remove the API key and leave it how it was written in the tutorial -

> src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"

instead of

> src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&key=replaceWithYourAPIKey"

(with my API key on the GCE dashboard inputted) - and it worked! Although with respect to functionality, it's not listing any bookstores within a defined radius as outlined in the example, but I think that may be an issue with how it was written in 2012 and how the maps API functions today.

Answer (score 1):

re: the maps key setup, this should work fine- I double checked it with a new key. However, it looks like the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key) are a bit out of date (I've filed a ticket for that), and perhaps that caused a glitch in your setup.  You want to turn on the API via the `APIs` pane in the [Cloud Console](https://console.developers.google.com/project), for the project in which you deployed the app.  Then, click on the `Credentials` pane and create a new "Public API access" key for browser applications.

For the search for 'nearby stores', there are only a few stores defined by default, and I suspect you are just not searching with a big enough radius.  Try e.g. 1500 km to test.  You can add new stores nearer to your location by editing `stores.py`.